# .NET Coogle Cloud Run can not access S3 bucket. "Permission denied"

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I have a .NET Api running in Google Cloud Run.
The app uses PostreSQL, Vision API and S3 servies of google cloud.
Vision API and the SQL DB works fine but...
When I try to upload a file into a bucket, I get the exception "System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException" with the message "Permission denied"

The point where the exception is thrown is:

```
var uploadedObject = await storageClient.UploadObjectAsync(bucketName, fullFileName, "image/jpg", imageBytesSream);
```

Stack trace:

```
at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-10-24 16:15:29.907 MESZ
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
2023-10-24 16:15:29.907 MESZ
   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.InitiateSessionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-10-24 16:15:29.907 MESZ
   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload.UploadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-10-24 16:15:29.907 MESZ
   at Google.Apis.Upload.UploadProgress.ThrowOnFailure(IUploadProgress progress)
2023-10-24 16:15:29.907 MESZ
   at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadHelper.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-10-24 16:15:29.907 MESZ
```

What I have checked/tried:

- IAM Service User for the application has the "Storage-Object-Creator" role and works in my local development. (Even with full admin rights no difference)
- I am developing in .NET 8 but I also tried a build wih .NET 7. No difference.

What did I forget to check?

Thanks :)

Ned